# Создание функции для pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Не судите строго) Я уже 5 часов ломаю голову и читаю литературу,но смысл понять не могу.
Есть запрос на сервер,который возвращает код ответа: `resp=requests.get('http://q.com')`. Мне нужно написать тест для проверки корректности кода по типу:

```
def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 5
```

Ниже мои попытки

```
import requests
def Test_fuction():
    resp=requests.get('http://q.com')
    return resp.status_code
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Результат: no tests ran in 0.12 seconds

Comment: `assert resp.status_code == 200` не выполнится, т.к. находится после `return`

Comment: test с маленькой буквы же, не?

Comment: Пробовал с маленько й-не помогает. Ниже дали пример через unittest. Им и буду пока пользоваться.Позже вернусь и попробую сделать работоспособным это код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Pytest собирает тесты из модулей с именами начинающимися на `test_` (хотя можно указать имя модуля явно при вызове pytest), классов на `Test` и функций на `test_`, а также может собрать все тестовые модули из папки `tests` (точных правил не помню, нужно смотреть документацию). Соответственно, функция у вас должна называться `test_function`.
2. Уберите из тестирующей функции `return`. Тестирующая функция не обязана ничего возвращать (хотя это и не запрещается), но в данном случае выход происходит до `assert`, поэтому проверка не выполняется. В примере из вашего вопроса `func` - тестируемая функция, она возвращает значение, `test_answer` - тестирующая функция, она ничего не возвращает, а просто проверяет результаты вызова тестируемой функции. `assert`ов в одной функции может быть несколько, например если мы проверяем сначала статус ответа, потом наличие какого-то текста в ответе и т.д.

Исходя из этого, файл `test_module.py`:

```
import requests

def test_function():
    resp=requests.get('http://q.com')
    assert resp.status_code == 200  # сначала проверяем статус
    assert 'welcome' in resp.text  # потом проверяем наличие слова welcome в ответе
```

Запускаем `py.test`, получаем результат:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.5.3, pytest-3.5.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: ***, inifile:
collected 1 item

test_module.py .                                                         [100%]

========================== 1 passed in 2.77 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: Очень информативный ответ! Спасибо,огромное!

Answer (score 1):

```
import unittest

import requests


class TRequest(unitest.TestCase):
    def test_simple_get(self):
        req = requests.get('http://q.com')
        req.raise_for_status()
        self.assertEqual(req.status_code, 200)


unittest.main()
```

Comment: Спасибо!попробую через unittest .Всё работает поправил код, пара неточностей было.